# Vertical margin not collapsing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin

In this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/munkii/tpQQN/ I have some margin bottom on the paragraph elements via the intro class and some margin bottom on the list items via the what-is class.

i.e.

```
article.about .what-is {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 34px;
    padding-right: 34px;
    width: 600px;
}

article.about p.intro {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 43px;
}
```

I have removed the unnecessary margin from my work but am still interested to know why Chrome is not collapsing the vertical margin when FF and IE does.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you notice that it disappears when you remove the height:100% from the .what-is li item?

Answer (score 0):

It can only be a bug.

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins these margins should be collapsed as we are in this case:

> bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height

`.what-is`' height should be computed as `auto` because

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)

The weirdest thing is that the computed height is indeed `auto`, but it seems Chrome doesn't do what it implies.

As Alex' comment states you can remove the `height: 100%;` rule, which lets the element takes its default height into account. `auto` that is.

Answer (score 0):

Well said MatTheCat.

Would it be because your height is 100%, Firefox takes the height of the containing Div as the height. Where as Chrome seems to include the margin bottom on the p tag into the height of the containing Div.

If that makes any sense...